# How to list orders in Prestashop 1.6 backoffice haveing no addresses assigned

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a prestashop where I have modified the ordering system in a way where no address needs to be assigned to an order. In this way the addresses fields have the values 0. 
The problem is that the backoffice does not list it, though all the data is saved in the database.
How could I do list those as well? Maybe I need to modify the sql query, but I dont know ehere to make that and how.

Answer (score 1):

The left join with table `address` fails to find rows because you're setting `id_address_delivery` in table `orders` to 0.

```
$this->_join = '
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer` c ON (c.`id_customer` = a.`id_customer`)
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'address` address ON address.id_address = a.id_address_delivery
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'country` country ON address.id_country = country.id_country
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'country_lang` country_lang ON (country.`id_country` = country_lang.`id_country` AND country_lang.`id_lang` = '.(int)$this->context->language->id.')
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_state` os ON (os.`id_order_state` = a.`current_state`)
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_state_lang` osl ON (os.`id_order_state` = osl.`id_order_state` AND osl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$this->context->language->id.')';
```

You can use a module hook to modify this before the list generates with `actionControllerNameListingFieldsModifier` to remove the address join part.

```
/*  AdminController getList() method

    Hook::exec('action'.$this->controller_name.'ListingFieldsModifier', array(
        'select' => &$this->_select,
        'join' => &$this->_join,
        'where' => &$this->_where,
        'group_by' => &$this->_group,
        'order_by' => &$this->_orderBy,
        'order_way' => &$this->_orderWay,
        'fields' => &$this->fields_list,
    ));
*/
public function hookActionAdminOrdersListingFieldsModifier($params) {
    // Remove address and country join clauses
    $params['join'] = '
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer` c ON (c.`id_customer` = a.`id_customer`)       
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_state` os ON (os.`id_order_state` = a.`current_state`)
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_state_lang` osl ON (os.`id_order_state` = osl.`id_order_state` AND osl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$this->context->language->id.')';
}
```